# Text in a Column ignores its textAlign attribute

Tags: flutter, text, text-alignment

Text in a Column ignores its textAlign attribute.

```
Text('Shop', textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
```

I am using Text in body: Container(child: Column(Text('Shop', textAlign: TextAlign.left,),),)

Comment: Could you try ```crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,``` for ```Column``` ?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the Text in a Container like so:

```dart
Container(
   width: double.infinity,  // Change width to whatever you need
   child: Text(
      'Shop', 
      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
   ),
),
```

And than your Text is aligned to the left inside the Container.

Answer (score 1):

Add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` for  the `Column`